# Turn off auto activation when deploying SharePoint 2010 feature

Tags: 2010, deployment, visual-studio-2012

I am building a SharePoint 2010 solution in Visual Studio 2012. When I deploy the solution, the features are automatically being activated. How do I disable this? Other answers have mentioned the "ActivateOnDefault" option, but I do not see this anywhere.

Comment: If you are F5 deploying in your dev environment, then don't do that. Simply package the wsp and do the standard PowerShell deployment.

Comment: Are you working on a Web application scope feature?

Comment: Actually, Eric, I am using Build|Deploy Solution. It works perfectly fine, and I don't have to use PowerShell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Web application scoped features are automatically activated at WSP deployment.
This is controlled by the `ActivateOnDefault` property you can find in the property window of the feature in VS. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms436075.aspx and the `ActivateOnDefault`  attribute.

Comment: Please tell me exactly where to find this property. When I click F4, I see "Build Action", "Copy to Output Directory", "Custom Tool", "Custom Tool Namespace" I don't see "ActivateOnDefault".

Comment: Double-click the feature in the Solution Explorer view, and the properties window should switch to a more detailed view including the `Activate On Default` property.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. It's the properties pane, WHEN the properties panel is open. I thought I was losing my mind.

Comment: same here.. without your comment i was lost searching the properties by pressing F4